# Определить язык произвольной строки

Tags: c#, .net, service

Задача: определить язык произвольной строки данных, пришедшей извне.

1. Можно ли это сделать средствами C#?
2. Есть ли сервисы, предоставляющие бесплатные API для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Есть точно. Много лет назад находил готовые решения, но сейчас не помню названия. А в общем задача решается детектом символов специфичных для языков и детектом языковых конструкций типа окончаний

Comment: Нашел старый велосипед. Источника не помню (по названию методов гуглится только php варианты которые похожи), да и код по меркам современного меня выглядит ужасно, но работает, да и вряд ли база языков устарела за это время. Только вот непонятно куда его положить по правилам so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Разумеется C# не обладает встроенными средствами, которым можно было бы скормить строку и получить язык, на котором она написана
2. Посмотрите [api Гугла](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language), возможно это то, что вам нужно

А вообще эта задача вряд ли может быть решена со 100% точностью. Можно придумать сколько угодно строк, язык которых нельзя определить однозначно (или вообще нельзя). Например строка "книга" может быть написана на русском, украинском или болгарском языках, а строке "saddfgdfhf" вообще вряд ли соответствует хоть один реально существующий язык.